# Ubuntu Server Randomly Dropping to BusyBox on Boot

Tags: server, fsck, busybox

It seems everytime I attempt to update/upgrade packages, the next boot drops to BusyBox. Sometimes it just randomly drops to BusyBox on restart. I can easily get out of BusyBox by running fsck and fixing all the errors it finds in the drive. I just don't understand why I keep having to do this. It is an enormous pain to run between rooms fixing my server every time I restart it. When I'm not at the same location at my server, I'm completely out of luck. I want to get this problem sorted and out of mind. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update: I realized that maybe the RAID 1 array it's in could be causing problems. This is the card I'm using: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00U7ZUSNW/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U7ZUSNW)

Comment: Sounds like your HDD has some bad sectors. Have you checked the SMART status?

Comment: I just ran a test, and it passed. They're fairly new Western Digital caviars in a RAID 1 array.

Comment: Hrrmmm. Well the fact that it is constantly getting filesystem errors is not a good thing.

Comment: Update: It now makes me run a manually fsck every single time it reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late answer. If anyone had this problem, it was because I was using a cheap RAID card that wasn't even really hardware RAID, or so it seemed. I deconstructed the array and reinstalled Ubuntu server edition. Haven't had that issue since.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it needed a delay to give the raid a chance. Taken from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2241430, I fixed it with:

```
# echo “sleep 60" > /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/delay_for_raid_array_to_build_before_mounting

# chmod a+x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/delay_for_raid_array_to_build_before_mounting

# udate-initramfs -u
```