# How to fix BusyBox Initramfs Error on Ubuntu 22.04 , showing many types of error

Tags: 22.04, initramfs, busybox, uuid, sgx

I am getting boot failure with this message on ubuntu 22.04:

```
[ 0.131760] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS. [ 1.974254] nvme nvmeo: failed to set APST feature (2)

Gave up waiting for suspend/resume

Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID=133c02c6-0569-4b52-84bf-7c7b0cecc5b2 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

When i reboot multiple times , Sometimes the system boots successfully and i can work on my ubuntu system like normal, But again next time when i turn on the laptop, Same issue arise.

I tried to enter ubuntu generic recovery mode ,but an endless process starts running , throwing infinite lines on screen.

i am using Asus tuf laptop, I can't find how to enable SGX in its BIOS.

How to to fix this ? Please Help. I am new to Linux. I don't want to reinstall and lose all my data.

Comment: Intermittent problems like this tells me it may be a hardware issue. Either your hard drive or SSD is failing or not connected properly.

Comment: See the following andwers: [One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802393/ubuntu-server-randomly-dropping-to-busybox-on-boot), [Two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49877/no-longer-able-to-boot-stuck-in-busybox-shell), [Three](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291284/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-20-04-lts-always-end-up-in-busybox). [Four](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811943/cant-boot-after-update-to-16-04-busybox-shell-appears).

Comment: @user68186   Update: I enabled secure boot, and now I am successfully able to boot the Ubuntu for 4 times consecutively, seems like it has worked. , Which tells me that , loose connection is not the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and after the required wait time, accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark  next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled "secure boot" from the BIOS, and now i am able to successfully boot the ubuntu OS.

> Secure Boot is part of the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI). The protocol defines a process that prevents the loading of unsigned drivers, boot loaders, or kernel modules (or those with unacceptable digital signatures).